# Agora cloud recording not saving to S3 and returning 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, agora.io

I am trying to save my audio feed to AWS S3.
Acquire and start call give proper response as given in the [documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=RESTful), but when I try to stop the recording it throws a 404 error code. Also the recording is not found in AWS S3 bucket.

Below are the request and response for each of the call

```
/acquire
#Request body 
body = {"cname": cname, "uid": uid, "clientRequest": {"resourceExpiredHour": 24}}
#Response
"Code": 200,
"Body":
{
 "resourceId": "IqCWKgW2CD0KqnZm0lcCzQisVFotYiClVu2jIxWs5Rpidc9y5HhK1HEHAd77Fy1-AK9piRDWUYNlU-AC7dnZfo6QVukbSB_eh3WqTv9_ULLK-EXxt93zdO8yAzY-3SGMPVJ5x4Rx3DsHgvBfnzJWhOvjMFEcEU9X4WMmtdXJxqjV3hhpsx74tefhzfPA2A7J2UDlmF4RRuINeP4C9uMRzPmrHlHB3BrQcogcBfdgb9DAx_ySNMUXGMQX3iGFuWBtjNRB4OLA2HS04VkSRulx3IyC5zkambri3ROG6vFV04jsPkeWb3hKAdOaozYyH4Sq42Buu7dM2ndVxCMgoiPDCi-0JCBL77RkuOijiOGQtOU-w9QKoPlTXRNeTur1MSfouE0A-4eDgu79FxK5abX7dckwcv9R3AExvs47U-uhmBh8vE6NXx4dQrXsu9Krx7Ao"
}


/start
#Request body 
body = {
        "uid": uid,
        "cname": cname,
        "clientRequest": {
            "recordingConfig": {
                "maxIdleTime": 30,
                "streamTypes": 0,
                "channelType": 0,
            },
            "recordingFileConfig": {"avFileType": ["hls"]},
            "storageConfig": {
                "accessKey": ACCESS_ID,
                "region": 8,
                "bucket": BUCKET_NAME,
                "secretKey": ACCESS_SECRET,
                "vendor": 1,
                "fileNamePrefix": [cname, TODAY_DATE.strftime("%d%m%Y")],
            },
        },
    }
#Response
"Code": 200,
"Body":
{
"sid": "fd987833cb49dc9ba98ceb8498ac23c4", 
"resourceId": "IqCWKgW2CD0KqnZm0lcCzQisVFotYiClVu2jIxWs5Rpidc9y5HhK1HEHAd77Fy1-AK9piRDWUYNlU-AC7dnZfo6QVukbSB_eh3WqTv9_ULLK-EXxt93zdO8yAzY-3SGMPVJ5x4Rx3DsHgvBfnzJWhOvjMFEcEU9X4WMmtdXJxqjV3hhpsx74tefhzfPA2A7J2UDlmF4RRuINeP4C9uMRzPmrHlHB3BrQcogcBfdgb9DAx_ySNMUXGMQX3iGFuWBtjNRB4OLA2HS04VkSRulx3IyC5zkambri3ROG6vFV04jsPkeWb3hKAdOaozYyH4Sq42Buu7dM2ndVxCMgoiPDCi-0JCBL77RkuOijiOGQtOU-w9QKoPlTXRNeTur1MSfouE0A-4eDgu79FxK5abX7dckwcv9R3AExvs47U-uhmBh8vE6NXx4dQrXsu9Krx7Ao"
}


/stop
#Request body 
body = {"cname": cname, "uid": uid, "clientRequest": {}}
#Response
{
    "resourceId": "IqCWKgW2CD0KqnZm0lcCzQisVFotYiClVu2jIxWs5Rpidc9y5HhK1HEHAd77Fy1-AK9piRDWUYNlU-AC7dnZfo6QVukbSB_eh3WqTv9_ULLK-EXxt93zdO8yAzY-3SGMPVJ5x4Rx3DsHgvBfnzJWhOvjMFEcEU9X4WMmtdXJxqjV3hhpsx74tefhzfPA2A7J2UDlmF4RRuINeP4C9uMRzPmrHlHB3BrQcogcBfdgb9DAx_ySNMUXGMQX3iGFuWBtjNRB4OLA2HS04VkSRulx3IyC5zkambri3ROG6vFV04jsPkeWb3hKAdOaozYyH4Sq42Buu7dM2ndVxCMgoiPDCi-0JCBL77RkuOijiOGQtOU-w9QKoPlTXRNeTur1MSfouE0A-4eDgu79FxK5abX7dckwcv9R3AExvs47U-uhmBh8vE6NXx4dQrXsu9Krx7Ao",
    "sid": "fd987833cb49dc9ba98ceb8498ac23c4",
    "code": 404,
    "serverResponse": {
        "command": "StopCloudRecorder",
        "payload": {
            "message": "Failed to find worker."
        },
        "subscribeModeBitmask": 1,
        "vid": "431306"
    }
}
```

My AWS bucket CORS policy is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-meta-custom-header",
            "x-amz-storage-class"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 5000
    }
]
```

Comment: What value are you setting for the bucket name?

Comment: The issue you are facing is a misconfiguration of the cloud recording settings. The value you are sending pass all the required checks so the server returns success on start, but since there is a config issue, the recording never starts so you get 400 errors on query and stop.

Comment: @Hermes Bucket name is file-storage-online, and can you explain a little further the second comment... FYI I am getting 404 error when stopping....

Comment: bucket name looks correct. For the second point (above). The way cloud recording service works is, the server receives the request, validates the POST data then uses the post data to start up the recording service. For this reason, sending the wrong config could cause the service to fail so you get start 200 and stop 400

Comment: The config is the hardest to trouble shoot because there are a few different things that can cause the issues, so I recommend first testing with the Agora Postman collection (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest) to ensure you've given the base variables correctly. Keep me posted if this helped

Comment: @Hermes... ok I will do this and get back to you... TQ

Comment: @Joish, Have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick was a little busy in other task yesterday and today.. will get back to this tomorrow.. will try it out and get back asap.... TQ

Comment: @Joish did you get solution for this? I am facing the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

I wanted to record a session even with one user, but seems that this is not possible, must be two users with different uid. Not sure why but at least the following worked for me.

Try:

1. Start your stream with one user like uid: 1
2. Connect with another device to the same channel but different uid.
3. Start recording
4. Before stop your recording make sure that query request is returning data
5. If you are getting data from query request, then your stream is recording.